# Instantiate View Controller not working

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, instantiation, skscene

I'm trying to load another `UIViewController` so that I can get the data of the `IBOutlets` inside of it. I'm using Swift and Sprite-Kit. The `UIViewController` I am talking about is called `GameViewController`. It is the first thing that loads up in my game. Then it goes to my `GameScene`. This is where I am trying to instantiate my `GameViewController`. I want to do this because I am using a library called `iCarousel` and I want to animate it moving up from my `GameScene`. However, iCarousel can only be used on a `UIViewController`. So I want to call a function in `GameViewController` that will be called in `GameScene`. In this function, there is an `NSLayoutConstraint` that is used to move the carousel. Whenever I call this function, it says that its nil. Here is some of my code:

Inside my `GameScene`:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let firstViewController: GameViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Load-up") as! GameViewController
firstViewController.start()
```

Inside my `GameViewController`:

```
func start() {
     // Constraint
     top.constant = 100
     UIView.animateWithDuration(2){
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

If you need more information, feel free to ask me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because your view controller hasn't loaded its view hierarchy yet. `viewController` loads its view hierarchy only when something sends it a `view` message. The system will do this by its own when to put the `view` hierarchy on the screen. And it happens after calls like `prepareForSegue:sender:` and `viewWillAppear:` , `loadView()`, `self.view`.

So here your `outlets` are still `nil` since it is not loaded yet.

Just try to force your VC to call `self.view` and then access the properties/outlets.

**Edit:** Added sample code.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let firstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Load-up") as! GameViewController
debugPrint("Printing for the sake of initializing view of VC: \(firstViewController.view)")
firstViewController.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... I don't really understand what you mean. Can you please give me a simple example in code of what you mean using the code that I have supplied? Thanks

Comment: Edited in my answer, please try now.

Comment: Thanks @Santosh, the method `loadView()` help me to instantiate it ( i am creating my cocoapod )